# Finding unique combinations of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a select query but am having trouble, probably because I'm not familiar with SQL Server (usually use `MySQL`).

Basically what I need to do is find the number of unique combinations of 2 columns, one a `Varchar` and one a `Double`.

There are less rows in one than another, so I've been trying to figure out the right way to do this.

Essentially pretend Table.Varchar has in it:

```
Table.Varchar
--------------
apple  
orange
```

and Table.Float has in it:

```
Table.Float
--------------
1   
2  
3.
```

How could I write a query which returns

```
QueryResult
-------------
apple1
apple2
apple3
orange1
orange2
orange3
```

Long day at work and I think I'm just overthinking this what I've tried so far is to concat the two columns and then count but it's not working. Any ideas to better go about this?

Comment: Are both these fields in the same table?  It sounds like they are, but then how can one field have fewer records than the other?  Do you mean that some values are null?

Comment: Can you show how these are actually stored in rows? Are the rows with apple and orange on the same rows as 1/2/3, or are there 5 different rows here? Is Table.varchar a table or a column?

Comment: What if Apple appears twice in varchar, or 2 appears twice in float?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select T1.VarcharField +  CAST(T2.FloatField as Varchar(10)) as [Concat]
from Table.Varchar T1
CROSS JOIN Table.Float T2
```

this way, you are generating the fields

so, then group by and use Count

```
select  T.Concat, count(*) from 
(Select T1.VarcharField + CAST(T2.FloatField as Varchar(10)) as [Concat]
    from Table.Varchar T1
    CROSS JOIN Table.Float T2) T
group by T.Concat order by count(*) asc
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are in the same table:

```
SELECT a.Field1, b.Field2
FROM [Table] a
    CROSS JOIN [Table] b
```

or if they are in seperate tables:

```
SELECT a.Field1, b.Field2
FROM [Table1] a
    CROSS JOIN [Table2] b
```

Keep in mind that the above queries will match *ALL* records from the first table with *ALL* records from the second table, creating a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: @AaronBertrand The first query will match each item in the first field (apple, orange) with each item in the second field (1,2) to produce apple 1, apple 2, orange 1, orange 2.  Can you do that without specifying the table twice?

Answer (score 1):

This will eliminate duplicates:

```
DECLARE @Varchar TABLE(v VARCHAR(32));

DECLARE @Float TABLE(f FLOAT);

INSERT @Varchar SELECT 'apple' 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'orange' 
  UNION ALL SELECT 'apple';

INSERT @Float SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3;

SELECT v.v + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), f.f)
 FROM @Varchar AS v
 CROSS JOIN @Float AS f
 GROUP BY v.v, f.f;
```

Answer (score 0):

A cross join is a join where each record in one table is combined with each record of the other table. Select the distinct values from the table and join them.

```
select x.Varchar, y.Float
from (select distinct Varchar from theTable) x
cross join (select distinct Float from theTable) y
```

To find the number of combinations you don't have to actually return all combinations, just count them.

```
select
  (select count(distinct Varchar) from theTable) *
  (select count(distinct Float) from theTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Possible Cominations.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT T1.VarField+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),T2.FtField) --Get Unique Combinations
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN Table2 T2 --From all possible combinations
WHERE T1.VarField IS NOT NULL AND T2.FtField IS NOT NULL --Making code NULL Proof
```

and to just get the Possible Cominations Count

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT T1.VarcharField + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), T2.FloatField))
FROM Table1 T1  
CROSS JOIN Table2 T2 
WHERE T1.VarcharField IS NOT NULL AND T2.FloatField IS NOT NULL
```